# Sharepoint workflow 2013, run when item has been modified by specific person

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have four workflows setup on a custom made SharePoint form.

1 workflow 2013 -> run when item created

2 workflows 2010 -> run when item modified

For the last workflow 2013, I was wondering if there is a way to make it run only when item has been modified by specific person.

A way other than using this command inside the workflow

```
If item modified by "Doe, John"
{
... other commands here
}
```

Comment: Should be no other better approach.

Answer (score 0):

No SPD workflows do not have a conditional start option.  You can do the same by implementing your logic in an event receiver that starts the workflow.  I've used SharePoint Power EventReceiver 2010 in the past for this purpose.  https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ilovesharepoint